# Add multiple sprites and assign to a group at once

Tags: python, pygame

Is there a way to quickly add lots of sprites, and add them to groups, without something like this:

```py
SA1 = SpriteClassA()
SA2 = SpriteClassA()
SA3 = SpriteClassA()
SB1 = SpriteClassB()
SB2 = SpriteClassB()
SB2 = SpriteClassB()

Group1 = pygame.sprite.Group()
Group2 = pygame.sprite.Group()
Group3 = pygame.sprite.Group()

Group1.add(SA1, SA2)
Group2.add(SA3, SB1)
Group3.add(SB2, SB3)
```

It's not bad with a few sprites and a few groups, but if I'm creating 1000 sprites and a few dozen groups... it would be nice if there was something to the effect of:

```py
SA1, SA2, SA3 = SpriteClassA()
Group1 = pygame.sprite.Group()
Group1.add(SA1, SA2, SA3)
```

or even better:

```py
SA1 - SA500 = SpriteClassA()
Group1 = pygame.sprite.Group()
Group1.add(SA1 - SA500)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of [`Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects and add the list to the [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

```
SA = [SpriteClassA() for _ in range(1000)]
SB = [SpriteClassA() for _ in range(1000)]
SC = [SpriteClassC() for _ in range(1000)]

Group1 = pygame.sprite.Group(SA)
Group2 = pygame.sprite.Group(SB)
Group3 = pygame.sprite.Group(SC)
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! Can I ask how you would make a Group4 that contained all sprites?

aaaaaand never mind, Group4 = pygame.sprite.Group(SA, SB, SC) seems to work